# Reducing the space on wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I couldn't get the rid of the spacing at the top of every page in my wordpress site.

Where can I see the px on my theme? So I can adjust it to be applied to all the pages on the theme instead of applying a piece of code to every single page.

[Click here to see the white spacing at the top](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5aE6.png)

[Click here to see the page demo](https://www.graspdating.com/tao1)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I don't know how I could upload my entire wordpress template here

Comment: You don't need the whole template...just enough to demo the issue. You might also find the issue as you reduce the code to the minimum required.

Comment: I really don't know how to do that, how can I provide a demo code if I'm asking about how to do something within a complete website? You could guide me, and I'll edit my post and post the code.

Comment: @Kamal for theme related settings please contact your theme's author/company for support.

Comment: I asked kinda the same question the other day here on Stackoverflow, and I got very helpful answer! Why are you asking me to do that? I'm reaching to experts here, I want to ask them not the theme guys. 
In case you knew the solution, why not just post it so me and others could benefit from it, and even people who are searching for the question in google.

Comment: The `article` tag is where the additional spacing (padding) is coming from.  This is `css` that is being embedded into the page, and is set to `!important`, so you won't be able to override it in an easily-editable `css` file for you theme.

This is likely to be an option that's been chosen within your theme, as that's how many of the WYSIWYG editors I've seen in Wordpress have embedded `css` into pages.

However, you have given no way near enough information for us to be able to help you sufficiently, nor demonstrated any real effort to have resolved the problem yourself.

Comment: Here's the css code: https://textuploader.com/dz3pm

Comment: How can I asign the page post to this code
.enl-page { 
padding: 20px 0px !important;
}

Comment: It depends on your theme, and any plugins that have been enabled.  It's likely to be inside the page editor, or perhaps some default page options in whatever theme you're using, but we can't see those options.

Comment: @Kamal is that css file you've posted actually editable from your dashboard, or have you just grabbed it from view source/inspect element?

Comment: It's editable, there's a video on the page I mentioned, and when the code is

Comment: Oh, just change that line then to `0 !important`.  I'll post an answer

Comment: Actually, that won't work.  The CSS rule that's applied is not in the CSS that you've supplied, there is another CSS file setting it to `20px 0px !important`

Answer (score 0):

go into wordpress dashboard, click appearance and click editor. Find the CSS file with the body declaration and put in:

```
         padding: 0;
         margin: 0;
```

This is liable to break all manner of things but will sort the first place that the padding/margin could be.

But you really need to post the CSS for us to have a clue

Comment: What CSS? Where can I find it?

Comment: Try changing the "35" in this, but there should be other CSS for the site:.enl-page { 
padding: 35px 0px !important;
}

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the bottom of your `css` file:

```
article.enl-page {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

It should achieve what you want.  It would be better to find out where the original rule is being set though.

Comment: Hey,
That did nothing